# How can I convert SQL Server date to custom formats

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime

2015-08-30 19:22:24.830
```

I need this output (in SQL Server)

```
2015-08-30 19   

2015-08
```

Comment: I hope you are not storing those strings

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), GETDATE(), 120) as "YYYY-MM-DD hh 1"
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120)  as "YYYY-MM 1"
    , FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd hh')    as "YYYY-MM-DD hh 2"
    , FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyy-MM')          as "YYYY-MM 2"
;
```

For any version of SQL Server you can use CONVERT(VARCHAR(),datecol,styleno)
just learn the relevant style numbers and adjust the length of the varchar

For SQL Server 2012 onward it's easier with the FORMAT() function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), GETDATE(), 120)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120)
```